# setting fonts with XeTeX+fontspec

Tags: xetex, fontspec

I am using Archlinux, emacs, XeLaTeX. I have some related problems.

1. I like the utopia font of the `fourier` package that I used to use before converting to XeTeX. Now, `fontspec` resets the font set by fourier.
2. When trying setting the font by `fontspec` as the example below, fontspec does not find the font!
3. Other fonts are found by `fontspec` but with ONLY using the `Path` option, although the font is found by `fc-list`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,article,twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{fontspec}
%\setmainfont{Adobe Utopia}
%\setmainfont{Utopia}[Path = /usr/share/fonts/Type1/]
\setmainfont{UTRG____.pfa}[Path = /usr/share/fonts/Type1/]

\begin{document}

This is to see whether it works.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep using your old font, it still works with XeLaTeX. Just do not load fontspec.

The problem with loading Adobe Utopia via fontspec is the font format: `UTRG____.pfa` is a pfa file, this is an ASCII encoded font.
To use the font with TeX, you need a binary font (.pfb). While you could convert the existing file with `t1binary`, the binary encoded Type1 Utopia font is already installed with TeXLive under the filename `putr8a.pfb`.

So to load the Type1 font with fontspec, use

```
\setmainfont{putr8a}[Extension = .pfb]
```

Then again, with XeLaTeX it would be better to use an Opentype version of the font. A free OpenType font derived from Adobe Utopia and available in TeX is `Heuristica`, so you should try

```
\setmainfont{Heuristica}
```

to get all the advantages of a Unicode based engine like XeLaTeX with a Utopia like font.

Comment: Thanks so much; 

1. For using `putf8a`, I had tried that already. However, it produces ugly output; I do not know why. it is not beautiful as `fourier` package.

2. Regarding using `fontspec`, I already using `Polyglossia` which loads `fontspec` either way.

3. I tried `Heuristica` after installing it from AUR, the result is not as beautiful as `fourier`. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: One more thing is that, when I use `fourier` after 'fontspec' the font renders very nicely as in `LaTeX`

Comment: Oops, I almost managed to produce a very similar compilation by using the scaling option:
`\setmainfont[Scale=0.925]{Heuristica}`
The only difference is that, the output by the `fourier` package seems to be a little bolder than the output with scaled `Heuristica`!

Comment: First you don't need to install Heuristica from the AUR, it's included in the texlive-fontsextra package. I can't see the difference in weight between the scaled Heuristica and fourier, but you might want to try the FakeBold option for `\setmainfont`: With `FakeBold=1.2` you get a slightly bolder version of Heuristica.

Comment: Thanks so much; regarding using the font from texlive, how can the system see it? Should I make a symlink to the fonts?

Comment: Why do you want the system to see it? XeLaTeX can see it, that should be enough.

Comment: My XeTeX does not see the fonts of TeXlive!! I have to install them system-wide or at least do a symlink to font folder. This is a surprise to me that XeTeX is able to see fonts of TeXlive. Could you help me please figuring this out.

Comment: I think this is relevant; right:
http://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-340003.4.4

Comment: Finally, I found it on the Archlinux page https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/TeX_Live  :

`sudo ln -s /etc/fonts/conf.avail/09-texlive-fonts.conf /etc/fonts/conf.d/09-texlive-fonts.conf`

`fc-cache && mkfontscale && mkfontdir`

Thanks so much